# Adding right padding-like space after last child in horizontally scrolling container without modifying the markup

Tags: html, css

The orange area represents the page; it has left and right paddings, but tabs ignoring the right padding:

[image]

There is the space between tabs (yellow background), but I need this space after last tab too:

[image]

`padding-right` does not work as expected: it does not add the space after last items.

**Desired result**:

[image]

**This is NOT desired result**:

[image]

Is there some pure CSS solutions?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nsz2bweh/3/)

Comment: plz review my answer .. is everything okay ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the last margin with a pseudo element:

```css
.minipage {
  width: 300px;
  height: 64px;
  background: #FFA07A;
  padding: 12px 14px 16px;
}

.tabsFlow {
  background: #FFFACD;
  margin-right: -14px;
  display: flex;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.tab {
  background: #E6E6FA;
  padding: 4px 8px;
}
.tab:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 12px;
}
.tabsFlow::after {
  content:"";    
  width: 12px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="minipage">
  <div class="tabsFlow">
    <span class="tab">Alpha</span>
    <span class="tab">Bravo</span>
    <span class="tab">Charlie</span>
    <span class="tab">Delta</span>
    <span class="tab">Foxtrot</span>
    <span class="tab">Golf</span>
    <span class="tab">Hotel</span>
    <span class="tab">India</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of a dumb hack, but you can get the illusion of the desired result by adding a background-colored right border to the last item:

```css
.tab:last-child
  border-right: 12px solid #FFFACD;
```

Your [fiddle with this added](https://jsfiddle.net/rayhatfield/kprjgLft/).

Answer (score 1):

**remove `margin-right` from `.tabsFlow` and `.tab` .. use border for `.tab` class**

**also change  to class `.minipage`**

```
.minipage {
   padding: 12px 0px 0px 12px;
}
```

```css
.minipage {
  width: 300px;
  height: 64px;
  background: #FFA07A;
   padding: 12px 0px 0px 12px;
}

.tabsFlow {
  background: #FFFACD;
  display: flex;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.tab {
  background: #E6E6FA;
  padding: 4px 8px;
   border-right: 16px solid  #FFFACD;
}
```

```html
<div class="minipage">
  <div class="tabsFlow">
    <span class="tab">Alpha</span>
    <span class="tab">Bravo</span>
    <span class="tab">Charlie</span>
    <span class="tab">Delta</span>
    <span class="tab">Foxtrot</span>
    <span class="tab">Golf</span>
    <span class="tab">Hotel</span>
    <span class="tab">India</span>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I am sorry, but you answer is a duplicate of @ray hatfield's one.

Comment: no.. i did not use last child .. i remove margin right from `.tabsFlow  .tab `.. use border for `.tab`  class .. how can be it duplicate with him ?

Comment: Sorry about this. Anyway one more problem left. Please check the "desired result" picture in my question. In your snippet, there is the orange space in the right part.

Comment: @Takesi Tokugawa YD i fix it... it's all about padding...

Comment: I accepted your answer and up-voted it. Why I has not give you the reputation prize is next limitation: your solution works only if there is no borders required by tabs design. I am not sure that possible to solve if without markup editing, so I'll give the reputation prize  to best answering when bounty will over, possibly to you.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is interested in a modern solution to this without using pseudo elements you can use a combination of `gap` and `padding` in the parent element to achieve the same result.

```css
.minipage {
  width: 300px;
  height: 64px;
  background: #FFA07A;
  padding: 12px 14px 16px;
}

.tabsFlow {
  background: #FFFACD;
  margin-right: -14px;
  display: flex;
  overflow-y: auto;
  /* ADD THIS */
  gap: 12px;
  padding-right: 12px;
}

.tab {
  background: #E6E6FA;
  padding: 4px 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="minipage">
  <div class="tabsFlow">
    <span class="tab">Alpha</span>
    <span class="tab">Bravo</span>
    <span class="tab">Charlie</span>
    <span class="tab">Delta</span>
    <span class="tab">Foxtrot</span>
    <span class="tab">Golf</span>
    <span class="tab">Hotel</span>
    <span class="tab">India</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the margin-right on your tabflow div

```
.tabsFlow

  background: #FFFACD
  // margin-right: -14px
  
  display: flex
  overflow-y: auto
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I am sorry about explained what I what enough clearly. I NEED this left margin. Your solution will work when 'tabsFlow' is transparent or it's color is even this parent's background. I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good approach, but I am sharing. Add an empty `span` tag with same class `tab`. Now check the css for last `tab` child I have added at the bottom of css code. The code will work, and the empty span tag will not be visible.

```css
.minipage {
  width: 300px;
  height: 64px;
  background: #FFA07A;
  padding: 12px 14px 16px;
}

.tabsFlow {
  background: #FFFACD;
  margin-right: -14px;
  display: flex;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.tab {
  background: #E6E6FA;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  margin-right: 12px
}

.tab:last-child{
  padding: 0 0.1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="minipage">
  <div class="tabsFlow">
    <span class="tab">Alpha</span>
    <span class="tab">Bravo</span>
    <span class="tab">Charlie</span>
    <span class="tab">Delta</span>
    <span class="tab">Foxtrot</span>
    <span class="tab">Golf</span>
    <span class="tab">Hotel</span>
    <span class="tab">India</span>
    <span class="tab"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am sorry, but because your solutions does not satisfy to conditions  "without modifying the markup", I can't vote up...

Answer (score 0):

You can get around this by not using flexbox...

```css
.minipage {
  width: 300px;
  height: 64px;
  background: #FFA07A;
  padding: 12px 14px 16px;
}

.tabsFlow {
  background: #FFFACD;
  margin-right: -14px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  
  /* Remove this */
  /* display: flex; */
  
  /* Add this */
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.tab {
  background: #E6E6FA;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  margin-right: 12px;
  
  /* Add this */
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="minipage">
  <div class="tabsFlow">
    <span class="tab">Alpha</span>
    <span class="tab">Bravo</span>
    <span class="tab">Charlie</span>
    <span class="tab">Delta</span>
    <span class="tab">Foxtrot</span>
    <span class="tab">Golf</span>
    <span class="tab">Hotel</span>
    <span class="tab">India</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The Flex method is not adapted to the result you seek.
The White-space Method is.
More info [here](https://codeburst.io/how-to-create-horizontal-scrolling-containers-d8069651e9c6).

Use `inline-block` for `.tab`. And `white-space: nowrap;` for `.tabsFlow`.

```css
.minipage {
  width: 300px;
  height: 64px;
  background: #FFA07A;
  padding: 12px 14px 16px;
}

.tabsFlow {
  background: #FFFACD;
  margin-right: -14px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.tab {
  background: #E6E6FA;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="minipage">
  <div class="tabsFlow">
    <span class="tab">Alpha</span>
    <span class="tab">Bravo</span>
    <span class="tab">Charlie</span>
    <span class="tab">Delta</span>
    <span class="tab">Foxtrot</span>
    <span class="tab">Golf</span>
    <span class="tab">Hotel</span>
    <span class="tab">India</span>
  </div>
</div>
```